# Reading Data From xlsx(Excel) File Data Is Not Showing

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, read-write

I have written some code for reading the data from excel file using Apache poi. Following is the code for the same:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\Book1.xlsx");     
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowiterator=sheet.iterator();

         while(rowiterator.hasNext()){
        Row row=rowiterator.next(); 
            Iterator<Cell> celliterator=row.cellIterator();
            while(celliterator.hasNext()){
                 Cell cell=celliterator.next();
                 switch(cell.getCellType()){
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: 
                    cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println("values========="+cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t\t");
                    empdata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                             break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"\t\t");
                    Double dblvalue= cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    int intval=dblvalue.intValue();   
                    empdata.add(Integer.toString(intval));
                    break;
                    }
        }
}
```

In the above code rowiterator  displays the rows and 
celliterator displays the cell values

Below is the my Excel file  structure Url:

```
http://img.viralpatel.net/2012/11/excel-file.png
```

But here I am not getting the values. Only the Emp Id index is getting printed, means first row and first column and first cell is printed on console.
Remaing cells are  not printed.

Plese suggest me  possible way.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `break;` within `case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:` statement. Try adding it and executing, good luck!

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t\t");
    empdata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
break;
```

**EDIT:** Copy the following inner while loop and please comment on what you get

```
              while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        // empdata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        Double dblvalue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        int intval = dblvalue.intValue();
                        // empdata.add(Integer.toString(intval));
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: am adding break ,but i forgot edit that, even also not working

Comment: I updated the answer with the exact inner while loop I'm using based on a similar-created excel sheet you are using. If you're referencing to the right worksheet, it should work!